# How to make <C-Space> work in terminal.app on mac?

Tags: macos, terminal-emulator, python-mode, jedi-vim

I want to use python-mode and jedi for autocompletion in Vim for python. However under my environment (vim 7.3 in terminal.app on OSX 10.8), I just cannot have the key-combination  work.

I read many related articles and knows that it is because terminal.app interpret  as  and I tried to use inoremap to change it but it does not work. Anyone has similar problem and figured out ideal solutions? Thx!

(In macvim with Gui there is no such problem, but I'd prefer run vim in terminal. I tried iterm2 but it also suffers.)

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I have "set paste" and it disabled all user-defined key mappings under insert mode.

It didn't influence GUI macvim since pasted mode was unnecessary for GUI editors.